# Download full journals from IEEE as pdf (ebook)

Tags: journals, ieee

I was wonder if anyone knew if it is possible (and how) to download an entire journal (as if it would be printed) from ieeeXplore ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe that violates the terms of use for IEEE Xplore.  I don't know if you are an IEEE member, institutional subscriber, etc., but the terms of use for institutional subscribers states the following:

> Institutional subscribers are NOT permitted to do the following: [...]
>
> - Download or attempt to download an entire issue or issues of a publication contained in IEEE Xplore.

You should first view the terms of use for IEEE Xplore at http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/termsOfUse.jsp, and if you have questions contact Xplore support via the contact form http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/techform.jsp.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to put legality aside merging pdfs into single file is rather easy (I assume that you can download individual articles as pdfs).

You need ghostscript program (avilable on any modern linux, and I guess also for windows) and then issue command:

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOUTPUTFILE=combinedpdf.pdf -dBATCH 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf
```

which will merge `1.pdf`, `2.pdf`, `3.pdf` into `combined.pdf`.

If you want to mass download articles you can use this firefox plugin: https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/downthemall/

Anyways: please mind that you might be bending or violating terms and conditions using these techinques.

Comment: I don't think that the problem that the OP wants solving is that he has all the articles in different PDF files ...

Comment: @xLeitix There is also information how to mass download the files ;)